# pipenv. Create Virtual Env. Acces denied

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I have Pipfile in my project folder.

I try to create VM for my project by using

> pipenv --python 3.9.6

But it doesn't work for me.

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: Path_to_Pipfile
Using c:/users/.../.pyenv/pyenv-win/versions/3.9.6 (None) to create virtualenv...
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...RuntimeError: failed to query c:\users\...\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.6 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I tried to uninstall pipenv, install python 3.9.6, but it doesn't help me.

Could anyone propose any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to run it with elevated rights (admin)?

Comment: Python virtual environments are neither VMs nor containers. They're a way to separate lists of Python packages, nothing more.

Comment: @Matt I work with VS Code and launch terminal there. But I saparetely launched terminal as adminstrator in Windows and try to do it and have the same problem.

Comment: Did you check the file/folder permissions for the `c:\users\...\.pyenv` folders and subfolders? Try to make you owner of this path (right click folder, select Properties -> Security -> Advanced and make yourself owner of the subtree).

Answer (score 1):

It worked to me to describe whole path to python instead version only.

> pipenv --python C:\Users\...\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.6\python.exe

But on another station it works only set a version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).